# Textfield hint in Android Studio is not positioned properly

Tags: android-studio, material-components-android

When I type in the Material UI Textfield, the hint is not positioning itself properly.
As you can see in this image, the hint is not properly positioned as it goes more left. I am just trying to do simple form in android studio

I am using Material Design 2 for UI and Kotlin for developing this android application.

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eafaee"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/copy___paste__2_" />


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle">
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#F8BA58"
            android:fontFamily="@font/niramit_bold"
            android:text="Login"
            android:width="160dp"
            android:height="40dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**build.gradle:app**

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```